# The order of bytes in a BMP scanline

Tags: bmp, endianness, scanline

I'm unsure as to whether it's BGR, then a NULL, or is it BGRBGR-> and then NULLs at the end to pad the width to a multiple of 4? Thanks for your time.

Comment: The code does not quite exist yet as I need this answered to continue past simply writing the header to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Found out after some few hours of trying to find a reliable source. Didn't think Wikipedia described it, but it's BGRBGRBGR-> then padding to a multiple of 4.